# I have an error "WebService returned a SOAP Fault"

Tags: error

i get an error when calling a webservice, i get the following error message

```
System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: Fault occurred while processing. faultcode=soap:Server faultactor=
```

I could not find the entire error message due to a salesforce limitation, here is the code that cause the error:

```
WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              'http://ws.ciphercloud.com/dpaas/detokenize',
              'http://ws.ciphercloud.com/dpaas/',
              'detokenizeRequest',
              'http://ws.ciphercloud.com/dpaas/',
              'detokenizeResponse',
              'DpaaSSoapWebService.DetokenizeResponse'}
            );
```

do you have an idea why i am getting this error Or how to trace the entire error message ?

Comment: You should post the response the service is sending. You should be able to get your callout from your debug logs and put that into postman or a similar app to see what the server response is.

Comment: how to get the callout from the debug (i am new to webservice)  ?

Comment: In your debug log there should be a line starting with `CALLOUT_REQUEST` that has the callout string.

Comment: Also you have your `CALLOUT_RESPONSE` just below it that will have the error in it. But I prefer to put the initial request into postman so I can tweak the body until I have fixed what is causing the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably not the answer to the OP's problem, but gives a run down of how to go about trouble shooting the issue.

**How to troubleshoot your problem**

- First grab the request from your debug logs.

Should be noted here that the `CALLOUT_RESPONSE` is just below the request. That will have your particular error. I just prefer to put it into Postman for readability as well as being able to alter the request "on the fly" to help solve the problem with the request.

[image]

- Put that into Postman or equivalent app

[image]

- See the response error

[image]

In this particular issue I had to track back to the original wsdl and found out that the `Type` is an enumeration. Which a `''` is not a valid value for. This probably won't be your particular issue. But I think this should get you going on how to find your issue.